# stty: : Invalid argument

Tags: scripting, solaris, telnet

I am telnet-ing into a Solaris machine and I'm getting the above error with my scripts. I realize this is a common problem, and the solution is to check for the line 'stty erase ^H' within my profile, but I can't find it.

.profile doesn't have any references to stty, and I don't have a .cshrc anywhere. I performed a grep in my home directory, but I came up with nothing.

Is there another source of this problem? All the solutions online refer to either .profile or .cshrc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this, it was an `stty` in .kshrc. Remember that .kshrc is sourced on all ksh scripts, interactive and non interactive.  If you run a script, stty will still fire, try to work on stdin, which is a file (not a tty now) and fail with an error.

Comment: I realized that that was the file I needed to look for. Unfortunately, I don't have any traces of it under any home directories or /etc/. I even created my own with "if ( $?prompt && { tty -s } ) stty erase ^?" and various other lines I gathered online with no luck. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I'd do: **(1)** log in. strace -p <pid of current shell> -o /some/file -f  **(2)** run your script **(3)** kill the strace **(4)** use your grep/sed skills to see all the file open()s in the strace log
**(5)** grep through those for stty.

I do this regularly when i don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

To trace your profile, try invoking your login shell with a name beginning with `-` and with the option `-x` so that it prints . To find out what your login shell is, run `getent passwd $USER`; your login shell is the last field on the line (usually `/bin/something`). To invoke the shell with a name beginning with `-`, make a symbolic link whose name begins with `-` and run that. For example, if your login shell is ksh:

```
ln -s /bin/ksh ./-ksh
./-ksh -x
rm ./-ksh
```

I'm not sure if this will work with csh. If you don't find anything interesting, look both in `/etc` and your dot files:

```
grep stty /etc/* ~/.* 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

From csh man page:

> A login shell begins by executing commands from the system files **/etc/csh.cshrc** and **/etc/csh.login**. It then executes commands from files in the user's home directory: first **~/.tcshrc** (+) or, if ~/.tcshrc is not found, **~/.cshrc**, then **~/.history** (or the value of the histfile shell variable), then **~/.login**, and finally **~/.cshdirs** (or the value of the dirsfile shell variable) (+). The shell may read /etc/csh.login before instead of after /etc/csh.cshrc, and ~/.login before instead of after ~/.tcshrc or ~/.cshrc and ~/.history, if so compiled; see the version shell variable. (+)

So there are a couple of files where you could find this line

Comment: I don't have any of those files, and I checked all the files in all the home directories (there are only 4 users on this machine). Also, I was dumb and didn't realize that the specific solutions probably only pertains to csh scripts, but the scripts in question are ksh. Furthermore, I tried adding my own .kshrc file with "if ( $?prompt && { tty -s } ) stty erase ^?" and various other lines I gathered online with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `tty` to test for tty: `tty -s && stty erase ^H`.

`tty -s`'s return code specifies if the current connection is tty or not.